# Show that for two partitions $\pi$ and $\rho$ of $\{1,...,9\}$ there are $x\neq y$ s.t. $\pi(x) = \pi(y) \text{ and } \rho(x) = \rho(y)$

Tags: combinatorics

For a partition $\pi$ of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$, let $\pi(x)$ be the number of elements in the part containing $x$.

Prove that for any two partitions $\pi$ and $\rho$, there are two distinct numbers $x$ and $y$ in $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ such that

$$\pi(x) = \pi(y) \text{ and } \rho(x) = \rho(y)$$

I have seen proofs by contradiction for this interesting problem and I would like to see more approaches and proofs.

Proofs by contradiction are welcome if they are different that what I've seen.

I was able to prove this by taking a part of $\pi$ and 'splitting' the elements into other parts of $\rho$, then showing by pigeon hole principle that at least two elements belongs to a part of the same cardinality of $\rho$.

Comment: Given a partition, I would study what the equivalence classes given by the relation $x\sim y$ iff $\pi(x)=\pi(y)$ might look like. Because rather than the parts of a partition, those equivalence classes are what you're really dealing with.

Comment: The function $\pi$ can take $3$ different values ($9=2+3+4$), at most.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions $\pi, \rho$ can take at most three distinct values, since $1+2+3+4 = 10 > 9$.

By checking cases, there must be a set of four elements $a, b, c, d$ with $\pi(a) = \pi(b) = \pi(c) = \pi(d)$.

Hence, there must be a pair these elements which have the same value by pigeonhole principle.

Comment: I get the part on many proofs to this problem that there can only be 3 different sizes at most of π and p. But I've seen the rest of a proof saying this :  If no such x, y exist, each pair π(x) and p (x) 
occurs for at most 1 element of x, and since there are
only 3×3 possible pairs, each must occur exactly once.
In particular, each value of π(x) must occur 3 times.
However, clearly any given value of π(x) occurs kπ(x)
times, where k is the number of distinct partitions of that
size. Thus π(x) can occur 3 times only if it equals 1 or
3. I don't get that part

Comment: Basically, let $a$ be some value taken by $\pi$. The number of $x$ for which $\pi(x) = a$ must be a multiple of $a$ (since these elements belong to some number of partitions each of size $a$)

Comment: What would be an example ?

Comment: I suppose a clear case is (1,2,3)(4,5,6)(7,8,9)

Comment: I suppose a clear case is (1,2,3)(4,5,6)(7,8,9) then if this was our 'π' then 'p' cannot be 3 for any values since clearly the elements in this 3  element subset partition (or part ) will be also in one of the parts of π . Kool I think I get it .

Comment: This particular problem has troubled me for quite sum time , thanks to m. Tong I can say it is over 60% resolved but please anymore solutions or comments welcome . I am wondering if anyone has any other problems very similar to this as in what branch of mathematics this problem stemmed from .

Comment: It becomes abundantly clear after realizing what the authors of this problem were thinking when they put it on one of the toughest math competitions in north America,  the putnam (1995) . It's a sneaky problem that can't be solved without pigeonhole concept.